# Hudson stopped working on my jboss

Tags: build, jboss, hudson

when i copy hudson to jboss i get following error on console

here i post error of jboss console

Is this problem of hudson or any other configuration

13:07:12,307 SEVERE [hudson.WebAppMain] Failed to initialize Hudson: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
    at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_01]
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:225) [:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3369) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3828) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_01]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_01]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_01]

13:07:12,335 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/hudson]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class hudson.WebAppMain: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
    at javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_01]
    at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:225) [:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3369) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3828) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]

13:07:12,338 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] Error listenerStart
13:07:12,338 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] Context [/hudson] startup failed due to previous errors
13:07:12,340 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.web.deployment:war=/hudson state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs/automount4814526bb3d939e0/hudson.war-ef6a3115c21523bd/ deployment failed
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:325) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]

13:07:12,348 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///D:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/hudson.war state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs/automount4814526bb3d939e0/hudson.war-ef6a3115c21523bd/ deployment failed
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:325) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///D:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/hudson.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs/automount4814526bb3d939e0/hudson.war-ef6a3115c21523bd/ deployment failed

```
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1316) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:968) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:82) [:6.1.0.Final]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are accidentally bundling Xalan or another xml jar in your classpath. Make sure you remove those lib and let JBoss use standard libraries. Try removing this jar from hudson.war xml-apis.jar.